# Perl File::Find duplicate names

Tags: perl, filesystems, perl-module

I'm using Perl's module File::Find to traverse across a directory.
This directory is an NFS share which has the directory .snapshot.
In this folder there's a snapshot of yesterdays file structure and thus it has directories with the same name in the result.
I therefore get the following error:

```
[folder_in_which_find_is_executed].snapshot/sv_daily.0 encountered a second time at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/File/Find.pm line 566.
```

Is there a way to prevent this from happening e.g. by removing the duplicate entry?

This is the code sub that executes the find:

```
sub process()
{
        my ($dev, $ino, $mode, $nlink, $uid, $gid, $rdev, $size,
            $atime, $mtime, $ctime, $blksize, $blocks) = stat $_;
        my $type = (-f _ ? 'f' : (-d _ ? 'd' : '*'));
        my ($md5sum);

        if (!defined $dev)
        {
                if (-l $_)
                {
                        die "Broken symbolic link: $File::Find::name";
                } else {
                        die "Error processing $type '$File::Find::name'";
                }
        }

        my $name = $File::Find::name;
        $name =~ s|^\.\/?||;

        if ($name ne '')
        {
                $db->{$name} = {
                        name => $name,
                        mode => sprintf("%04o", $mode & 07777),
                        user_id => $uid,
                        group_id => $gid,
                        last_modified => $mtime,
                        type => $type
                };

                if ($type eq 'f')
                {
                        $db->{$name}->{size} = $size;
                        $db->{$name}->{inode} = $ino;
                        $md5sum = SumForEntry($name, $_);
                        $db->{$name}->{md5sum} = $md5sum;
                }
        }
}
```

The following line executes this sub:

```
find({ wanted => \&process, follow => 1}, '.');
```

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Stock question: Why are you using the empty prototype?

Comment: @Hugmeir: why not? File::Find manual says _The wanted function takes no arguments but rather does its work through a collection of variables._

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler : I didn't ask because it was incorrect, only because it's generally bad form. If he had quoted that from the docs, that's all fine and good, he knows how prototypes work. If he didn't know, chances are he'd use it again later on and create a hard-to-find bug. tl;dr: To me, asking "Why are you using prototypes" is alike asking "Why aren't you using strict?".

Comment: @Hugmeir: your expanded comment is reasonable - and helps the OP.  Your initial comment is perhaps a little too Perl-terse to help.  Maybe a pointer to some article about the (many) demerits of Perl prototypes would help.  Unfortunately, Tom Christiansen's "Perl Prototypes Considered Harmful" is not on the internet that I can find (with Google) any more; the Internet Archive declines to divulge it because of a robots.txt file at perl.com.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: You are right remarking the terseness - My original intent was to link to either that or the full FMTEYEWTK series, but it seems we hit the same barrier there! Thankfully a search in PerlMonks has just turned up results: Far More Than Everything You've Ever Wanted to Know about Prototypes in Perl:  http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl/index.pl?node_id=861966 FMTEYEWTK: http://www.mediafire.com/?2gmzng76ln2e9dj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'wanted' function can tell [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) to prune its search:

> The function may set $File::Find::prune to prune the tree unless bydepth was specified.

On entry to the snapshot directory, set the prune variable to prevent further processing of it.